# disable submit button if there is any error in the validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation

i need to hide the submit but if there is any error in validation. i'm using the below code where if i entered both the text boxes with characters and if i correct 1 of the text box the submit button turns visible! how to avoid it util all the errors are clear?
Thank you

```
int num;

private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(textBox5.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        button2.Visible = false;
        errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox5, "Please enter numbers");   
    }
    else
    {
        button2.Visible = true;
        errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox5, "");
    }
}

private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(textBox6.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        button2.Visible = false;
        errorProvider2.SetError(this.textBox6, "Please enter numbers");
    }
    else
    {
        button2.Visible = true;
        errorProvider2.SetError(this.textBox6, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that both text boxes are error free before setting the button visibility to `True`. You can use another method for this, as I did below using `UpdateSubmitButton`.

This method checks if either `textBox5` or `textBox6` has an error associated with it, then updates the visibility of `button2` accordingly. Note that I removed the other `button2.Visible` assignments from each of the `TextChanged` events, and replaced it with a call to the `UpdateSubmitButton` method.

```
private void UpdateSubmitButton()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError) &&
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider2.GetError))
    {
        button2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button2.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(textBox5.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox5, "Please enter numbers");   
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox5, "");
    }
    UpdateSubmitButton();
}

private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(textBox6.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        errorProvider2.SetError(this.textBox6, "Please enter numbers");
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider2.SetError(this.textBox6, "");
    }
    UpdateSubmitButton();
}
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'GetError' and no extension method 'GetError' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of textboxes you validate, you could create a function that validates everything in one shot.

```
bool ValidateAll(){
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(textBox5.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        return false; 
    }

    isNum = int.TryParse(textBox6.Text.Trim(), out num);
    if (!isNum)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then call this method of all TextChanged event you want to monitor